# can FTP user steal sourcecode of website?

Tags: php, ftp

Hello i created a FTP account and set it to access only certain folder "xyz". i want to ask you can he access php scripts files saved in parent folder by uploading a php script file to ftp folder "xyz" ie. "file manager script".

for example if domain root is:

http://xyz.com/mainsite/xyz

i set him to access only xyz folder. but if he uploads any php script in "xyz" folder than can he download php files saved in "mainsite" folder ?

Comment: Why not put your FTP folder outside of your website tree ?

Comment: In general terms. Any PHP script in any folder can access any files that the user php is running as can access. SO if your www-data/apache/nobody user can access a file then a php script run in your web server can also access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That totally depends on the server configuration, but you can test this yourself by creating an PHP file in the FTP folder:

```
echo file_get_contents('../foo.txt');
```

Comment: Not letting users upload files to your wwwroot or a subdirectory of that will be a start.

Comment: a ftp user can upload any file, how can i stop him uploading php files ?? please..!!

Comment: It's not about the file type, but their location and the permissions. There is too little information in your question to give a good answer (why do you need users to upload files through FTP, why is that directory a sibling of wwwroot, and so on). How to set up server permissions would perhaps also be a better question on another site, like SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: i have developed a web application worth $1200, i want to allow users just to upload image files in particular folder. FTP is faster so i gave him ftp.

Comment: Giving people access to the database admin interface also is faster than building an HTML form to let them post comments, but that doesn't mean it's the best way. Anyway like hinted a few times: **don't allow them to upload to a subdirectory of your wwwroot**.